# Automatically clear all data when closing Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a setting to automatically clear user data when you sign out of chrome?  I have students logging in and it is "remembering" them.  I want it to delete user data when they sign out of chrome.
Thanks!

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: Please use proper titles when asking questions.

Comment: what does that mean? Use proper titles when asking questions?

Comment: It means that “Is there a setting available?” is not a useful question title. It doesn’t tell us anything.

Answer (score 1):

create a new shortcut to Chrome on the desktop.  Edit the Target with "-incognito" at the end.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito

This will remove logins when the user closes out of the browser.